# Wordpress Header Background Image Issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress

After hours of trying different things and codes, I came here to seek some help (I'm beginner in coding).

I'd like to put a full width and full height background image only in the header. The site is here: http://www.coveragenewstv.com/

Here is header.php :

```
<head>
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' );?>" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php
wp_head(); /** we hook up in wp_booster @see td_wp_booster_functions::hook_wp_head */
?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class() ?> itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="<?php echo td_global::$http_or_https?>://schema.org/WebPage">

<?php //this is closing in the footer.php file ?>

<?php /* scroll to top */?>
<div class="td-scroll-up"><i class="td-icon-menu-up"></i></div>

<div id="td-outer-wrap">

<div class="td-transition-content-and-menu td-mobile-nav-wrap">
    <?php locate_template('parts/menu-mobile.php', true);?>
</div>

<?php //this is closing in the footer.php file ?>
<div class="td-transition-content-and-menu td-content-wrap">

<?php
td_api_header_style::_helper_show_header();

do_action('td_wp_booster_after_header'); //used by unique articles
```

Comment: You shouldn't be making changes to your header.php if you want a background image. You're using WordPress. You can set a background image on the dashboard.. There will be some options according to the theme you are using.. Check out customize under appearance..

Answer (score 1):

Add two code-blocks to **the bottom** of your css file:

```
.td-banner-wrap-full, .td-header-menu-wrap-full {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

and

```
.td-header-wrap.td-header-style-1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Replace the url to your background image url.

[See: Works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG1GG.png)

Comment: Hello,Thank you for that. I did these steps now but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: Here is the existing code of style.css for my current header (Style 1): github.com/waseem3302/coveragenewstv/blob/master/style.css @vuza

Comment: @waseemKhan: I checked your live website and can't find the extra code.

Sure you uploaded it? There should be a style.css file in your wordpress theme folder, put it to the bottom of this file!

Maybe you got an caching plugin like WP Super Cache, which loads old, unchanged CSS files for page-loading-time reasons?

Comment: Hello, there is no cache plugin installed. I've put your code at bottom of my style.css and I tried viewing on an other browser after clearing cache too. No results at all. Here is the complete style.css file: github.com/waseem3302/coveragenewstv/blob/master/thestylecss @vuza

Comment: Also, I don't want the image on navigation bar, just need above it.